# capturing image and displaying it in imageview in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I'm trying to implement camera in my android app. I'm able to take a picture from camera but when trying to display it in imageview I'm getting some error and I tried to find the solution for it but couldn't find one. I
m trying to implement camera in a fragment instead of an activity and using navigation complement.

Any help would be really helpful.
Thank you in advance.

This is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2451208 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2451208 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4408)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
```

This is code written in my fragment.
I even tried to reduce the size of the image by calling the function getResizedBitmap().

```
binding.clickPhotoImageview.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext() , Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
//                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
            } else {
                val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
            }
        }
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val photo = data!!.extras!!["data"] as Bitmap
            photo!!.height = 150
            photo!!.width = 120
            val image: Bitmap? = getResizedBitmap(photo, 200)
            binding.clickPhotoImageview.setImageBitmap(image)
        }
    }

    fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap? {
        var width = image.width
        var height = image.height
        val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize
            height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
        } else {
            height = maxSize
            width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
    }
```

Comment: `I'm getting some error` Some error? Name it!

Comment: It does not make sense trying to resize the obtained bitmap as it is only a thumbnail that you get. No full picture. Just look at its width and height.

Comment: `photo!!.height = 150
            photo!!.width = 120` ?? What are you trying to achieve? Please remove statements.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2451208 bytes` means that you are trying to send too much data through bundle. Instead, try to save the image somewhere on the disk and then load it from there, as shown for example here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0 Check out their samples